# using Cauchy's formula in $\int_C\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let C be the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. So $\int_C\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz$ can be written as $\int_C \frac{sin(z)/z}{z-0}dz = 2\pi i f(0)$ which is undefined. So am I allowed to write it as follow: $$\int_C \frac{sin(z)/z}{z-0}dz = \lim_{\alpha \to 0}\int_C\frac{sin(z)/z}{z-\alpha}= \lim_{\alpha \to 0} 2\pi if(\alpha) = 2\pi i$$ I am having doubts if this can be used, but $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is holomorphic in $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin z}z&\text{ if }z\ne0\\1&\text{ if }z=0.\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is holomorphic and therefore, by Cauchy's integral formula,\begin{align}\int_C\frac{\sin z}{z^2}\,\mathrm dz&=\int_C\frac{f(z)}z\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi if(0)\\&=2\pi i.\end{align}

Comment: What happens when the assumptions is that $\sin(z)/z^2$ is undefined in $0$?

Comment: That's a fact: it *is* undefined at $0$. What's the problem?

Comment: You are defining $\sin /z$ at $z = 0$, and I am wondering why we can do this and if I keep it undefined if my aproach works.

Comment: I am most definitely *not* defining $\frac{\sin z}z$ at $0$. I defined a function $f\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}z$ if $z\ne0$ and that $f(0)=1$. It turns out that this function $f$ is holomorphic. On the other hand, if I defined a function $g\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that $g(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z^2}$ if $z\ne0$ and that $g(0)$ is some complex number $\omega$, then, no metter which $\omega$ I would have chosen, $g$ would not be holomorphic.

Comment: Ok I understand, you've helped me on numerous occasions I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Define$f(z)=\frac{sin(z)}{z^2}$In this very case is useful to develop with exponential remind that $sin(z)=Imm(e^{iz})$.

So let $e^{iz}=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}=\sum_{(2k)}^{\infty} \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}+i\sum_{(2k+1)}^{\infty} \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}$ so $sin(z)=\sum_{(2k+1)}^{\infty} \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}$ so $sin(z)=z - \frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}...$

follows that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z} - \frac{z}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{5!}...$ is the Laurent series associated to your function. By def $Res(f,0)=a_{-1}=1$

So using Residue Theorem $\int_Cf(z)dz=2\pi iRes(f,0)=2\pi i$ noting that $0$ is the only pole in C.